# How to remove elements from a list based on the field values of objects in another list

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-stream

I have two lists of objects. `List<Obj1> and List<Obj2>`.

```
class Obj1
{
    private int id;
    private String x;
}

class Obj2
{
     private int id;
     private String y;
}
```

Now how can I remove the objects from `List<Obj1>` whose elements satisfy `obj1.x==obj2.y`

Comment: This question is not clear. What is the purpose of id? Moreover, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify `obj1.x==obj2.y`. It's not clear if you need this based on index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be collecting second list object `obj2` property `y` into `Set`

```
Set<String> ySet = objs2.stream().map(Obj2::getY)
.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

And then you can use `removeIf`

```
list1.removeIf(obj1->ySet.contains(obj1.x));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
obj2.forEach(per -> ids.add(per.getId()));

List<Object> result = obj1.stream().filter(per -> ids.contains(per.getId())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```